# R : Trying to order data in a data frame which is in a list

Tags: r

I'm trying to order my data in a data frame, which is organized in a list

I'm sorry I can't show you the full data, but the data looks something like this (This is just an example)

Name / EducationStatus/ CurrentSalary

What I'm tried to do is first, classify everyone by their education status.

```
salaryRank <- function(outcome, rank){
    dataFile <- read.csv("salary.csv", colClasses = "character")

    if(outcome == "CurrentSalary"){
        dataFile$CurrentSalary <- as.numeric(dataFile$CurrentSalary)
        dataFile <- split(dataFile, dataFile$EducationStatus)
    }
}
```

From this I retrieve

Bachelor
<- eg) a data frame with Emily, John, Michael and Mark

High School Grad
<- eg) a data frame with Anthony, Tom, and Elizabeth

Master
<- eg) a data frame with Laura, David, and Jennifer

Now, I want to rank their salary by order. So if I type 3 in the rank section, It would eventually retrieve the 3rd place person in each data frame(Bachelor, High School Grad, and Master).

However, I was unable to find any kind of option that I might use to perform this. I tried every x-apply method but I was unable to reach the 'Education.Status'section. Something like output$$Education.Status didn't workout...

Thx in advance.

Comment: Tried this? df_ordered <- df[order(df$CurrentSalary),]  which gives you the ordered data frame, then you could do df_ordered[3,] to get the third row

Answer (score 0):

You can order your data frames with the function order() like this:

```
df_ordered <- df[order(df$CurrentSalary, decreasing=TRUE),]
```

...then to get the third row use this:

```
df_ordered[3,]
```